# Agora-SDK [ERROR]: [866CE]None Ice Candidate not allowed

Tags: agora.io

I had agora rtc integrated in my website few months back and it was running smoothly until recently when the remote video is not being seen, and upon checking in the console, there is an error that says

> Agora-SDK [ERROR]: [866CE]None Ice Candidate not allowed.

Comment: can you provide a link to see the error? Also can you update the question to include steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: any updates on the possible solutions to this question?

Comment: nope, the problem was pretty much browser specific. Happened only in my chrome browser, but on mozilla working fine. Tested on other devices too and it was working fine. The problem was no longer occurring after few days.

Answer (score 0):

Agora has provided the reason and solution to this problem in this [documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/console_error_web#none-ice-candidate-not-alloweda-namecandidatea),

> **Reason:**
>
> When establishing a WebRTC connection, the SDK fails to find any ICE (Interactive Connectivity Establishment) candidate.
>
> **NOTE:** A candidate contains the IP address and port information for connecting to a remote device.

> **Solution:**
>
> The type of candidates used for connection depends on whether you have enabled [cloud proxy](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/cloud_proxy_web?platform=Web) or not. Choose one of the following solutions accordingly.
>
> - If you have enabled cloud proxy, the SDK gets relay candidates from a TURN server. Check whether you have whitelisted the IP addresses and ports that Agora provides for cloud proxy, and ensure that the local client can connect to the TURN server.
> - If you have not enabled cloud proxy, the SDK gets host candidates from the local device. In this case, the error is usually caused by the security settings of the local device.
>
>   - Check whether the browser has any plugins that disable WebRTC.
>   - Ensure that you have enabled UDP in the system firewall, and added the [specified domains and ports](https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/firewall?platform=All%20Platforms#web-sdk) to the whitelist.